# How to fetch row from array.? mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am working with codeigniter. I want to fetch a single row with passed index. If I pass `0` then first row should be display if `2` then second. etc

Here is my little code.

```
$qu['tid'] = mysqli_query($con , "select * from tablename");        
$this->load->view('admin/panel1' , $qu);
```

view code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $tid['id'];?></td> // given row if 1 or 2
        <td><?php echo $tid['name'];?></td>// given row if 1 or 2
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$this->db->get('table_name')->row_array()` returns first row in array format.

To fetch the specific row pass the row number as parameter.Like below

```
$row = $this->db->get('table_name')->row_array(2);//fetches the third row
```

**Example**

Controller:

```
$qu['tid'] = $this->db->get('table_name')->row_array();        
$this->load->view('admin/panel1' , $qu);
```

view:

```
echo $tid['id'];//prints id
```

Comment: I want to change it latter with variable.

Comment: why downvoted?any explain please

Comment: I want echo one row like this `echo $tid['id'][0]`, second `echo $tid['id'][1]` third `echo $tid['id'][3]`.. ** HOw can fetch specific row from whole array variable.?**

Comment: use result_array() and foreach loop.